# Insert JSON array of objects into postgreSQL using object keys as column names

Tags: javascript, sql, json, postgresql

I have application written in Javascript which uses postgreSQL (9.6) DB to store data. 
Is there a way how to insert Javascript object directly into DB ?

I created this example table:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  "uuid" uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" text NOT NULL,
  "phone" number
);
```

Javascript object in the app:

```
{
  uuid: 'df7c5fdc-d6b7-4b5e-ac3b-1228fac64a90',
  name: 'Martin',
  phone: 123456
}
```

Now I have the array of different people (array of objects above) and I managed to insert it to DB in this way:

```
let uuids = people.map(p => `'${p.uuid}'`) // adding quotes, otherwise syntax error
let names = people.map(p => `'${p.name}'`)
let phones = people.map(p => `'${p.phone}'`)

INSERT INTO people (
  "uuid",
  "name",
  "phone"
)
VALUES (
  UNNEST(ARRAY[${uuids}])::uuid,
  UNNEST(ARRAY[${names}])::text,
  UNNEST(ARRAY[${phones}])::number
)
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently ? like in mongo `db.collection.insertMany(array)` ? Also, I'd like to omit some of the values and have them `NULL`, which is not possible in this example.

I was searching in PostgreSQL docs and there are several functions to work with json but I couldn't find any suitable for this.

Thank you for help.

Comment: What makes you think there is anything inefficient about that?

Comment: Postgresql's `json_to_recordset()` function looks promising when combined with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` as a way to do it entirely in SQL.

Comment: "adding quotes, otherwise syntax error" sounds like an SQL injection in the making.

Comment: @Pointy well, the creation of three new arrays with map is weird. In my app, I have more than 10 properties, so it means more than 10 new arrays which were all UNNESTed after.

Comment: @IljaEverilä it seems to be quite safe after JSON.stringify

Comment: If that means "pass the string result of `JSON.stringify` to the query using proper placeholders", then it is safe. If you're still string formatting/concatenating the result to a query string, probably not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a chance to test `json_to_recordset()`:

```
INSERT INTO people("uuid", name, phone)
SELECT "uuid", name, phone
FROM json_to_recordset(?) AS x("uuid" uuid, name text, phone int);
```

where the placeholder should be bound to an array of objects like you describe (Except in proper JSON, of course).

[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ca43b/1)

Comment: That works, I just had to do `json_to_recordset(JSON.stringify(myArraw))`, thank you!